# Not able to implement background image in HTML email template in GMAIL/OUTLOOK

Tags: email-template

I am trying to send a `background image` in email. I am using `HTML email template without Letterhead`. On Preview, I can see the background image but it is not displayed when send to email server. I have tested with GMAIL and outlook.

`HTML email template`

```
<html>
<head>
<body style="position: relative";>

  <div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="20%" width="20%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

  <table height="40%" width="40%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        testing background image
    </tr>
   </table>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

On Preview:

[image]

But In GMAIL/OUTLOOK, I am only seeing `testing background image`

Comment: Check if you have to enable download pictures in Gmail/ Outlook

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like that, please change the width and  height values based on your expectations:

```
<html>
<head>
<body style="position: relative";>

   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#7bceeb" background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" width="100%" height="400" align="center" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px; height:600px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#bdd731" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
             <![endif]-->

                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" align="left"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

                          <tr>
                            <td >testing background image</td>
                          </tr>

                        </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]--></td>
              </tr>
            </table>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```